# How to calculate High Score in game when there are two units in the game?

Tags: unity, leaderboards

In my game I am solving a problem, and I am getting certain points for each problem.
Just like collecting numbers falling from the top.

Now I want to calculate a high score on the basis of two items i.e. solved points and time it took to solve until the user get it wrong.

How would I rank any player based on the two events?

Comment: Presumably you tried doing something simple like multiplying the solved points and the time by a weighting coefficient each, then adding the results together? Is there something you find unsatisfactory about that simple approach that we can help you improve upon? Also, are you *really* using the deprecated language [tag:unityscript], that has not been supported in Unity for several years now?

Comment: In my game, 1st it was how much time player can survive and 2nd way to collect points was the same as collecting coins for which the player will be awarded 1 or 2 points depending upon different objects. Now on leaderboard either can be max time survived or total coins collected. I want to know how I can calculate high score by combining both.

Comment: Would any of these do the trick: `(total points) = (1st way) + (2nd way)` or `(total points) = (1st way) * (2nd way)`?

Comment: If both ways units were some like int points then I can add or multiple. But 1 way is time unit and 2nd way is int points. Has anyone noticed how high score is calculated in games like - Subway Surfer, Temple Run.

Comment: Time can be represented as a number just fine. "Number of seconds" or whatever.

Comment: Doesn't this depend on whatever you want as a score in general? If your collectables are just 1 or 2 points, you can say every few seconds (play with what 'few' means) will be 1 point, so at the end, you divide the time by that amount and add an x amount of points to the collected points. if you later decide (like temple run etc) it's more fun to have bigger numbers, every collectible gives 100 or 200 points, and so at the end you calculate the points for time as mentioned above and give 100 points instead of 1. I think it really comes down to what you want.

Comment: If you're asking how to convert time to int, if your player survival time is stored as a TimeSpan, then you can do something like `timePoints = (int)System.Math.Floor(time.TotalSeconds / secondsPerPoint)`

Comment: Honestly there are many approaches you can take to solve this and the solution you pick depends on how high of a number and how precise you want your scores to be (for example is 1,000,000 points normal or is it just 0% to 100%). Usually what I do is something like `float pointsPerSecond = 1.0f; float pointsPerCoin = 10.0f; int finalScore = (int)(survivalTimeInSeconds * pointsPerSecond) + (int)(coinsCollected * pointsPerCoin);` It's a simple formula and should help you keep your scores in a predictable range without limiting the max score.

Comment: If you want to keep your score is a specific range you can add the following `int maxScore = 1000000; int minScore = 0; finalScore = Mathf.Clamp(finalScore, minScore, maxScore); float finalScoreInPercent = (float)(finalScore - minScore) / (maxScore - minScore);` Honestly you probably don't need a minScore value, but you could use it to make people feel better if they play terribly by giving them some bonus points for playing.

Comment: @BejaminDangerJohnson want to share that as an Answer below?